# Unable to get environment variables values that are in Docker container

Tags: spring-boot, docker-compose, environment-variables

I am building a spring boot application with a REST API. I am using Spring Boot version 3.1.0-RC1, from Spring Milestone Repository. We are using spring-boot-docker-compose to automate the running of docker compose file.

The problem is, I am having trouble getting the environment variables from the docker container. The docker container successfully runs, and by executing `docker exec -it <ContainerName> sh`, and `env`, it displays the environment variables correctly.

However, when running System.getenv(""); or @Value(${}) from SpringBoot, it returns null for a String value and 0 for an integer.

This is the docker-compose.yml file.

```
version: '3.9'

services:
  file2vec-service:
    image: file2vecservice:latest
    ports:
      - "3033"
    environment:
      SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE: "production"
      <ENV_VAR1> : "xxx"
       etc...
```

Please advise, thank you.

We tried to run `docker-compose up` in terminal manually and found that it works with `System.getenv`. However, that defeats the purpose of using spring-boot-docker-compose.

Hence we are trying to find a way to get the environment variables through spring-boot:run and use the docker-compose from spring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring Boot's Docker Compose support doesn't start your Spring Boot App with Docker Compose. It just runs the services that your application is using, like a database or a messaging system.

Therefore the environment variables are not used.

You must configure the application either in a development application.properties file (maybe using profiles) or as configuration in your run configuration in your IDE.